# How to check one rows value present in any of the other column row value

Tags: python, pandas

I have excel like below

```
A B
1A 100 
2A  1A 
3A  101
5A  1A
```

Expected out is

```
A B   Bool
1A 100  
2A  1A  True
3A  101 
5A  1A   True
```

Here you can see that `1A` present in df['A'] is present in df['B]

I tried like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pdf.read_excel('test.xlsx')
df['A'].isin(df['B'])
```

but its not working

Comment: Swapped `B, A` ? `df['B'].isin(df['A'])` for me working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A':['1A','2A','3A','5A'],
    'B':[100,'1A',101,'1A']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

With this code, you will have the following dataframe:

```
    A    B
0  1A  100
1  2A   1A
2  3A  101
3  5A   1A
```

You can correct the third column in this way by using the iterrows()

```
df['Bool'] = False
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if df['B'][index] in list(df['A']):
    df['Bool'][index] = True
```

The output is:

```
    A    B   Bool
0  1A  100  False
1  2A   1A   True
2  3A  101  False
3  5A   1A   True
```

But this is not a good solution. Without iterrows() you can do as follows:

```
df['Bool'] = df['B'].isin(df['A'])
```

The output is the same:

```
    A    B   Bool
0  1A  100  False
1  2A   1A   True
2  3A  101  False
3  5A   1A   True
```

Or with lambda:

```
df['Bool'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: True if x in list(df['A']) else False)
```

The output is the same:

```
    A    B   Bool
0  1A  100  False
1  2A   1A   True
2  3A  101  False
3  5A   1A   True
```

**Why is it better not to use iterrows() and loop on df?**

- SettingWithCopyWarning:
  Usually, when you run iterrows() on the rows in pandas, and at the same time change a value in the dataframe, you get the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

- RunTime:

```
df.iterrows()         Time:  0.010589972999696329
df['B'].isin(df['A']) Time:  0.002069372000050862
lambda                Time:  0.005262545000732643
```